# Mysql count and sum from two different tables

Tags: mysql, count

i have a problem with some querys in php and mysql:
I have 2 different tables with one field in common:

table 1

id | hits | num_g | cats | usr_id |active

1  |  10  |  11  |  1   | 53     | 1

2  |  13  |  16  |  3   | 53     | 1

1  |  10  |  22  |  1   | 22     | 1

1  |  10  |  21  |  3   | 22     | 1

1  |   2  |   6  |  2   | 11     | 1

1  |  11  |  1  |  1    |  11     | 1

table 2

id | usr_id | points

1  |  53    |  300

---

Now i use this statement to sum just the total from the table 1  every id count + 1 too

```
SELECT usr_id, COUNT( id ) + SUM( num_g + hits ) AS tot_h FROM table1 WHERE usr_id!='0' GROUP BY usr_id ASC LIMIT 0 , 15
```

and i get the  total for each usr_id

usr_id| tot_h |

53    | 50

22    | 63

11    | 20

until here all is ok, now i have a second table with extra points (table2)
I try this:

```
SELECT usr_id, COUNT( id ) + SUM( num_g + hits ) + (SELECT points FROM table2 WHERE usr_id != '0' ) AS tot_h FROM table1 WHERE usr_id != '0' GROUP BY usr_id ASC LIMIT 0 , 15
```

but it seems to sum the 300 extra points to all users:

usr_id| tot_h |

53    | 350

22    | 363

11    | 320

Now how i can get the total like the first try but + the secon table in one statement? because now i have just one entry in the second table but i can be more there.
thanks for all the help.

---

hi thomas thanks for your reply, i think is in the right direction, but i'm getting weirds results, like

usr_id |  tot_h

22  |   NULL   <== i think the null its because that usr_id as no value in the table2

53     |    1033

Its like the second user is getting all the the values. then i try this one:

```
      SELECT table1.usr_id, COUNT( table1.id ) + SUM( table1.num_g + table1.hits + table2.points ) AS tot_h
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.usr_id = table1.usr_id
WHERE table1.usr_id != '0'
AND table2.usr_id = table1.usr_id
GROUP BY table1.usr_id ASC
```

Same result i just get the sum of all values and not by each user, i need something like this result:

usr_id | tot_h

53     |  53    <====  plus 300 points on table1

22      | 56    <====  plus 100 points on   table2

/////////the result i need ////////////

usr_id | tot_h

53     |  353    <====  plus 300 points on table2

22      | 156    <====  plus 100 points on   table2

I think the structure need to be something like this
Pseudo statements ;)

from table1 count all id to get the number of record where the  usr_id are then sum hits + num_g and from table2 select the extra points where the usr_id are the same as table1 and get the result:

usr_id | tot_h

53    |  353

22   |  156

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in your subquery which calculates extra points to correlate it to the outer Table1. So, one solution is to add that correlation:

```
SELECT usr_id
    , COUNT( id ) + SUM( num_g + hits ) 
    + (SELECT points 
        FROM table2 
        WHERE table2.usr_id = table1.usr_id ) AS tot_h 
FROM table1 
WHERE usr_id != '0' 
GROUP BY usr_id ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 15
```

Another solution would be to simply join to it directly:

```
SELECT table1.usr_id
    , COUNT( table1.id ) 
        + SUM( table1.num_g + table1.hits + table2.points ) 
        AS tot_h 
FROM table1 
    Left Join table2
        On table2.usr_id = table1.usr_id
WHERE table1.usr_id != '0' 
GROUP BY table1.usr_id ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 15
```

Answer (score 0):

i think get the solution, i dont know if its the best but it works for me, if you know a way to optimize this i really apreciate it.

```
SELECT usr_id , COUNT( id ) + SUM( num_g + hits )as sumtot ,
      (SELECT points FROM table2  WHERE usr_id = table1.usr_id ) AS tot_h
FROM table1
WHERE usr_id != '0'
GROUP BY usr_id ASC
```

with this i get something like this

usr_id |sumtot | tot_h

5      |557    |  NULL

53     |2217   |  300

So then i just sum the result and show it in a while loop.

```
<?php
//some mysql here
//then the while loop
// and then the final sum

$final_result=$r_rank['tot_h']+$r_rank['sumtot'];

 ?>
```

Thanks a lot  for your help thomas :)